# How to represent this VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

```
typeof(Nullable<>)

public static bool IsNullableType(Type t)
        {
            return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
        }
```

I was using this to check whether Lambda Expressioin parameters are nullable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do this yourself - you can just use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx) which returns `Nothing`/`null` if the type you pass it isn't nullable:

```
Public Shared Function IsNullable(t as Type) As Boolean
   Return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) IsNot Nothing
End Function
```

(But if you really need an open generic type, then `GetType(Nullable(Of))` will work. If you need multiple type parameters, just comma-separate them, e.g. `GetType(Dictionary(Of ,))`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() Is GetType(Nullable(Of )))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function IsNullableType(t As Type) As Boolean
    Return t.IsGenericType AndAlso t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = GetType(Nullable(Of ))
End Function
```

Used the following free tool to convert:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/